# converting date format in Javascript and calculating difference between two dates

Tags: javascript, date

I have two dates in Javascript-

1. In the format `16-Feb-2016`.
2. In the format `26-01-2015`.

Now i have to get the **difference** of both the dates using javascript in years and months.

I am not getting how to do it because both the dates are in different format.

Comment: There are many questions and answers here about parsing dates, the formats in the OP require about 3 lines of code. Getting the difference in years and months is not trivial, I don't think Moment.js does that accurately. Have a look at the answer [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504942/how-to-get-the-difference-of-two-dates-in-mm-dd-hh-format-in-javascript/35520995#35520995) (which includes a parser that can easily be modified to suit the formats here).

Answer (score 1):

Paste the following code in console and check. Hope it helps.

```
    var d1 = "16-Feb-2016";
    var d2 = "26-01-2015";
    var date1 = new Date(d1);
    // The date to be formatted in mm-dd-yy
    var date2 = (d2).split("-");
    date2 = date2[1] + "-" + date2[0] + "-" + date2[2];
    date2 = new Date(date2);

    function getDiff(date1, date2) {
    var monthDiff= (date1.getFullYear()*12)+(date1.getMonth()+1)-(date2.getFullYear()*12)-(date2.getMonth()+1);
    var diffYear = parseInt(monthDiff/12);
    var diffMonth = monthDiff%12;
    return (diffYear + " years, " + diffMonth + " month");
    }

    var difference = getDiff(date1, date2);
    console.log(difference);
```