# how get the distance in years,months and day from two timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

Suppose I have two timestamp:

```
var timestamp1=Date.now();
var timestamp2=Date.now();
```

and we know that timestamp1

Comment: There are plenty solution online, just need to dig a bit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: In what units do you expect the difference/distance?

Comment: If you want the difference in years, months, days, etc. you might also want to look at the answers here: [*How to get the difference of two dates in mm-dd-hh format in Javascript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504942/how-to-get-the-difference-of-two-dates-in-mm-dd-hh-format-in-javascript/35520995#35520995). It's not a simple task as years, months and days do not have a consistent length, differences are not necessarily symmetric and there are a couple of business rules that may vary depending on local preferences.