# PHPbb3 Javascript inline count down timer using BBCODE dates not quite right

Tags: javascript, date, phpbb3

Appologies if this is in the wrong area!

Ive trying to create an 'inline' in post event count down timer, ideally using BBcode so forum users can create countdown timers to certain events.

What i have so far pretty much works however some of the maths isn't quite right, and so while most dates show up correctly some don't and I'm at my wits end trying to work out where ive gone wrong! Can someone have a look and point me in the right direction - to be clear - the code I'm using is not my own.

Im on PHPBB 3.2.0

BBCode Usage

`[event={NUMBER1}/{NUMBER2}/{NUMBER3}]{TEXT}[/event]`

HTML Replacement

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
 // February has 29 days in any year evenly divisible by four, EXCEPT for centurial years which are not also divisible by 400.
 function daysInFebruary (year) {
  return (((year % 4 == 0) && ( (!(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))) ? 29 : 28 );
 }
 var Eventtext = "<strong>{TEXT}</strong>" ;
 var Future  = new Date('{NUMBER1}/{NUMBER2}/{NUMBER3}');
 var Today  = new Date();
 var daysinmonth = { 1:31, 2:(daysInFebruary(Today.getYear())), 3:31, 4:30, 5:31, 6:30, 7:31, 8:31, 9:30, 10:31, 11:30, 12:31 };
 var F_Year = Future.getYear();
 var F_Month = Future.getMonth();
 var F_Day = Future.getDate();
 var years = 0;
 var months = 0;
 var days = 0;

 while( F_Year  != Today.getYear()  ) { if ( F_Year < Today.getYear() ) { F_Year++; years--; } else { F_Year--; years++; F_Month++;} }
 while( F_Month != Today.getMonth() ) { if ( years < 0 ) { months = Today.getMonth()-F_Month; break;} else { if ( F_Month < Today.getMonth() ) { F_Month++; months--; } else { F_Month--; months++; } } }
 while( F_Day   != Today.getDate()  ) { if ( years < 0 ) { days = Today.getDate()-F_Day; break;} else { if ( F_Day < Today.getDate() ) { F_Day++; days--; } else { F_Day--; days++; } } }

 if ( years > 0 ) {
  if ( days < 0 )   { days = daysinmonth[F_Month]-Math.abs(days-1); months--; }
  if ( months < 0 ) { months = 12-Math.abs(months-1); years--; }
 }

 if ( !years && !months && !days ) { document.write(" Today is " + Eventtext); }
 else if ( !years && !months && days == 1 ) { document.write(" Tomorrow is " + Eventtext); }
 else if ( !years && !months && days == -1 ) { document.write(" Yesterday was " + Eventtext); }
 else  { 
  var word_year = ( Math.abs(years) == 1 ) ? " year, " : " years, ";
  var word_month  = ( Math.abs(months) == 1) ? " month, " : " months, ";
  var word_day = ( Math.abs(days) == 1 ) ? " day" : " days";
  var word_elapsed= ( Future > Today ) ? " until " : " since ";
  var Output  = (years != 0) ? Math.abs(years) + word_year: '' ;
  Output += (months != 0) ? Math.abs(months) + word_month  : '' ;
  Output += (days != 0) ? Math.abs(days) + word_day  : '' ;
  document.write(Output + word_elapsed + Eventtext); }
</script>
```

Help Line

`[event=DATE]NAME THE EVENT[/event] Example : [event=2008/09/22]Next workday[/event]`

testing this on todays date on my forum (Todays date been: 2018/03/10: YYYY/MM/DD) i get the following results (ive shown the event code infront of each for ease)

`[event=2018/03/09][/event]`Produces: Yesterday  - correct

`[event=2018/03/10][/event]` Produces: Today  - correct

`[event=2018/03/11][/event]`Produces: Tomorrow  - correct

`[event=2019/03/09][/event]`Produces: 1 year, 26 days - wrong

`[event=2019/03/10][/event]`Produces: 1 year, 1 month,  - 1 month out

`[event=2019/03/11][/event]`Produces: 1 year, 1 month, 1 day  - 1 month out

As you can see some dates work perfectly some don't - any help would be gratefully received

Comment: Regarding: `new Date('{NUMBER1}/{NUMBER2}/{NUMBER3}')` do not do that, ever. It's extremely error prone to construct a string, then have the unreliable built-in parser parse it. Just give the values directly to the constructor as `new Date(year, month - 1, day)` where *month* is the calendar month number: 1 for Jan, 2 for Feb, etc.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) and [*How to get the difference of two dates in mm-dd-hh format in Javascript.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504942/how-to-get-the-difference-of-two-dates-in-mm-dd-hh-format-in-javascript)