# Convert number of days left into years, months, days

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get the difference between two dates (my birthday and the current date to get the time left until my birthday), But I want the output format in ('Year/Months/Days); How can I do that? that's what I've tried so far :

```
 const birthday = new Date ('11-20-2021').getTime();
 const today = new Date ().getTime();
 const dys = (1000*60*60*24);
 const months = (dys*30);
 let differance = birthday-today ; 
 const formatted = Math.round(differance/dys);
 console.log(formatted);`
```

thank you in advance

Comment: what would you consider a month? Is the difference between `March 2nd` and `February 1st` 1 month and 1 day, or 29 days?

Comment: There are [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+difference+between+dates+in+years%2C+month) on this already, with some good answers with and without libraries, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35520995/257182), please excuse the shameless self promotion… :-)

Answer (score 0):

How do you feel about the modulo operator?  :)

This is a common math operation, like finding change or such.  Think of it this way, if you have a large number of days, say 397, you can get number of years by doing integer division (1), then you can get the number of days left by doing modulo by a year to get the remainder (in days) 397%365 = 32.  Then you can repeat the process to get number of months remaining (1...assuming 30 day month) in that and again, modulo to get the final number of days 2 ...

I'm no javascript pro, but I think you need to use Math.floor(quotient) to get the result of division in integer format.

Comment: Honestly !! i was thinking exactly the same way you've looked at it, but I thought it may be some other ways to get around that, but thank you so much for taking time to answer my concern ;) appreciate you

Comment: The [`%` multiplicative operator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-multiplicative-operators) in ECMAScript gives the remainder of dividing two numbers, it's not strictly a modulo operator, see [*JavaScript % (modulo) gives a negative result for negative numbers*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467624/257182).

Answer (score 0):

this example compares between the current date and the date 2100/0/14 try the same concept in the example and i hope it helps:

```
var today, someday, text;
today = new Date();
someday = new Date();
someday.setFullYear(2100, 0, 14);

if (someday > today) {
  text = "Today is before January 14, 2100.";
} else {
  text = "Today is after January 14, 2100.";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Sorry maybe i wasn't clear when writing my question but what I needed from that is to output exactly how many years, months, and days left until my birthday. For instance how many days left from today until March 3rd, 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Working with dates and differences can be difficult because there are a lot of edge cases. which is why I prefer to let a dedicated library handle this, like https://momentjs.com/

moment has a plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-precise-range-plugin) which does exactly what you are looking for:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-precise-range-plugin';

var m1 = moment('2014-01-01 12:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var m2 = moment('2014-02-03 15:04:05','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var diff = moment.preciseDiff(m1, m2, true); // {years : 0, months : 1, days : 2, hours : 3, minutes : 4, seconds : 5}
var str = `Years: ${diff.years}, Months: ${diff.months}, Days: ${diff.days} `; // 'Years: 0, Months: 1, Days: 2'
```

Comment: I actually did but I am still having the ' moment.preciseDiff is not a function', I tried to find out where the problem is but it doesn't look like there is something obvious. I am putting the lines of code I wrote so maybe it'll give you an idea on what I am talking about 
   `var m1 = moment('2017-05-17 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    var m2 = moment('2022-05-17 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    var diff = moment.preciseDiff(m1, m2);
    var str = `Years: ${diff.years}, Months: ${diff.months}, Days: ${diff.days} `;
    document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML = diff; `

Comment: Most likely you didn't import `moment-precise-range-plugin`. It's a plugin, so the import appears to be pointless, but it's not because it actually modifies the `moment` library.

Answer (score -1):

If I got you right, I've done it this way.
Haven't touched your original code, but added a function that calculates the dateTime output of the total days of difference.

```js
const birthday = new Date('11-20-2021').getTime();
const today = new Date().getTime();
const dys = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
const months = (dys * 30);
let totalDayserance = birthday - today;

const formatted = daysToDateTime(totalDayserance / dys);
console.log(formatted);


function daysToDateTime(totalDays) {
  var baseVal = '';
  var formedValues = [
    ['Years', 365],
    ['Months', 30],
    ['Days', 1]
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < formedValues.length; i++) {
    var valueByGroup = Math.floor(totalDays / formedValues[i][1]); //by months

    if (valueByGroup >= 1) {
      baseVal += (valueByGroup + formedValues[i][0]) + ', ';
      totalDays -= valueByGroup * formedValues[i][1];
    }
  }

  return baseVal;
}
```